# ODBC Query cannot be executed because it is too complex?

Tags: macos, csv, libreoffice, odbc

I have a CSV file which I am using as a database with LibreOffice DB.
What I'm doing is explained in detail in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/8746/8435).

I can do some operations, but when I try to enter the following into the SQL editor:

```
select SUM(Dollars) from original
```

I get the following error:

> The query cannot be executed.  It is too complex.  Only Count(*) is supported.

So I think its an error from the ODBC or maybe JDBC driver.  Where can I find a better driver for my MacBook OSX 10.7.2?  Or what else should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the Base driver for file-based database drivers (i.e. those using csv files as databases) simply does not support most of the standard SQL aggregate functions. The best you can do is to keep the most current version installed and wait if you intend to stay with CSV format.

I would strongly suggest moving from CSV to a "real" database format such as LibreOffice's native database format. That will enable full use of SQL syntax. Instructions on how to do that are available here:

http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=58501#p258835

Comment: it was just a project for my brother, i didn't really want to mess with a full db app.  But i guess its the right way to go.