# Query CSV like SQL and generate graphs and charts?

Tags: web-application

Is there an application or website that takes CSV files, loads them into a DB, allows SQL queries to be run on them and then creates charts or graphs with the results?

**
Update: I installed MAMP, and that was very painless. 
**
Here's the import statement for anyone who comes across this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/musicdata.csv' INTO TABLE MusicData FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' (DistributionYear, `Distribution Quarter`, `Statement Recipient ID`, `Statement Recipient Name`, `Party ID`, `Party Name`, `Legal Earner`, `Legal Earner Party ID`, Performance, `Music User Genre`, `Music User`, `Network Service`, `Performance Start Date`, `Performance End Date`, `Survey Type`, `Day Part Code`, `Series or Film/Attraction`, `Program Name`, `Work ID`, `Work Title`, `CA%`, `Classification Code`, `Number of Plays`, `Performance Type (Usage)`, Duration, `Performing Artist`, `Composer Name`, `EE Share`, Credits, Dollars, `Premium Credits`, `Premium Dollars`, `Adjustment Indicator`, `Adjustment Reason Code`, `Original Distribution Date`, `Role Type`);
```

Comment: Why doesn't a spreadsheet program like excel (or access) work? What are you missing? You want to write in SQL or you'll write in anything, like VBA?

Comment: @Raystafarian Well I installed LibreOffice on my Mac, import CSV as DB, then tried to run SQL queries on the data, but the "Query is too complex - only select is supported - ODBC driver error. The query was just a SUM(column) with a Where clause.

Comment: Then you seem to have [the typical XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) – rather than looking for workarounds, why not ask a new question in order to tackle the actual problem you have?

Comment: @slhck http://superuser.com/questions/379652/update-odbc-driver-on-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), with the [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) frontend management tool. It allows you to [import CSV files](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/import#CSV) to a table. Of course, you have to define the table and database schema beforehand.

Then, you can run SQL queries with phpMyAdmin, which is pretty straightforward. PMA also [supports Charts](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Charts).

The results can be exported as CSV again. Actually, graphing or producing charts is not as easy as you might think. To make assumptions about the data format, or the kind of graphs you want to produce, a graphing utility has to be very powerful. Various tools exist, some of the more popular ones:

- Microsoft Excel
- [R](http://www.r-project.org/), also with the [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) library
- [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)
- [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Comment: So I guess you kinda have to roll your own... I can do it but I was hoping for a lazier solution.

Comment: This is only what I thought of. Maybe there's something, who knows! But the problem obviously is SQL. It works well on databases, not necessarily CSV files. And then there's graphing too.

Comment: Only on a Mac? in Windows you could set up an odbc datasource that is txt or csv and query it from lots of things on your system, webpages, excel or what have you. Perhaps Macs allow the same?

Comment: @datatoo Ah, well I'm not too experienced when it comes to that, but yes, of course ODBC is *possible* on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's Log Parser is ready-made for this.  No need to log data into a database.

[More here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659)

Answer (score 2):

[sqliteviz](https://lana-k.github.io/sqliteviz/#/) (which I'm the author of) has everything you need. It is a free open-source offline-first PWA that allows you to convert a CSV file into SQLite database which runs in a browser with [sql.js](https://sql.js.org/#/). After that, you can filter your data with `SELECT` statements and create various [Plotly](https://plotly.com/javascript/) charts against the result set.

### Convert your CSV into a database

Choose your CSV file. Sqliteviz will show you the `Import CSV` dialogue with data preview and parsing settings like delimiter character and others.
[image: sqliteviz CSV import dialogue]

### Filter your data with SQL

Now all records from your CSV are available as rows in `csv_import` table of SQLite database. Filter them with SQL.
[image: sqliteviz query result set]

### Create a chart

After running a query switch the result panel to the chart mode. Here you can create a chart with a `react-chart-editor` component. The same component with some additional features is used in Plotly Chart Studio. Explore its [documentation](https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/tutorials/#basic) to learn how to build charts with `react-chart-editor`. You can create various charts from simple line/bar/pie chart to financial candlesticks and scientific visualisation.
[image: sqliteviz chart example]

In sqliteviz you can also save often-used queries and import/export them.
See sqliteviz [documentation](https://github.com/lana-k/sqliteviz/wiki).

Comment: This turned out to be a very useful tool. Thank you for sharing.